# How can I make a form remember the input for a virtual attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

In my view, I have

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

where tag_list is a virtual attribute.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def tag_list
    #Virtual attribute stuff
  end

  def tag_list=(value)
    #Virtual attribute stuff
  end
end
```

The problem is that when the user submits the form and it doesn't pass validation, the form doesn't remember the input for tag_list field. It only remembers the input for the name field. How can I make the form remember the input for tag_list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it in the session when you get the form params in your controller action.

**Example:**

> ```
> def new
>   @post = Post.new
>   @tag_list = session[:tag_list]
> end
>
> session[:tag_list]= params[post][tag_list]
> @post = params[post]
>
> if @post.save 
>   ...
> else 
>   ...
> end
> ```

and now in your form, use @tag_list to populate tag_list

```
<%=f.text_field, :tag_list, @tag_list%>
```